# Dynamically setting size of HTML5 canvas based on the mobile screen

Tags: javascript, css, html, cordova, canvas

I want to make a mobile webpage for Phonegap, it consist of a header and a context, the context contains a canvas.
I want to make the canvas fill 100% of the content div, and the content div to fit 80% of the whole screen.

here is my code so far

```
<div id="mappage" data-role="page"> 
    <div id="maphead" data-role="header">
    I am the Header
    </div>
    <div id="mapcontext" data-role="context">
    <canvas id="map" style="background: black">
    </canvas>
    <script>
        map.onload = map.onrezise = function(){
            var canvas = document.getElementById("map");
            canvas.style.position = "fixed";
            canvas.setAttribute("width", map.innerWidth);
            canvas.setAttribute("height", map.innerHeight*0.8);
                    canvas.style.top = map.innerHeight * 0.2 ;
        }

    </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

All i get is a black canvas, new size is not applied, the top style is not applied.

thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, event name is

> resize

Second, you must set event to window. For example

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('map');
    canvas.style.position = 'fixed';
    canvas.style.width = innerWidth + 'px';
    canvas.style.height = innerHeight*0.8 + 'px';
    canvas.style.top = innerHeight*0.2 + 'px';
});
```

Comment: It worked by adding "load" instead of "resize" as i wanted it to be in the start of the app as well as when it is resized.
Thanks alot

Comment: I think that setting the Canvas size to the Div and set the Div to the 0.8 i want will be better cause like this the content Div has 0 height.